# Am I missing a repository?

Tags: apt, repository

I think I might've accidentally removed the main Ubuntu repository after trying to remove a different repository. In the attached screenshot it shows what repositories I have, am I missing any? If I am, what would be the command to add it back?

[screenshot of software repositories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjeHN.png)

Comment: is [this reference](https://news.itsfoss.com/mozilla-vpn-linux/) of any help?

Comment: No, I probably shouldn't have included the bit about Mozilla VPN, that just complicated my question. My issue is that I'm pretty sure I accidentally removed an important repository. I need confirmation if I did, and if I did I would need a command to add it back.

Comment: I think it does. After I created a new file, it was populated with some things. Two of the entries were related to Mozilla VPN. My guess is that I originally only saw one of them and removed that one, went back in and was confused why there was another, then assumed that I must've deleted the wrong one.